# Encountered infinite recursion while looking up resource 'Arg_NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib

Tags: c#, .net, windows, nullreferenceexception, .net-7.0

My program was developed in .Net 7 (VS 2022) and running on non-English Windows 10 (x64). Most of the time my program works normally. However, the following error (in Event Viewer) was thrown sometimes, then it will show a dialog and my program quits.

How can I solve the issue? It seems that it is a problem related to .Net...

Thanks.

```
Application: XXX.EXE
CoreCLR Version: 7.0.1323.51816
.NET Version: 7.0.13

Description: The application requested process termination through
System.Environment.FailFast.

Message: Encountered infinite recursion while looking up 
resource 'Arg_NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.

Verify the installation of .NET is complete and does not need
repairing, and that the state of the process has not become corrupted.

Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.SR.InternalGetResourceString(System.String)
   at System.SR.GetResourceString(System.String)
   at System.NullReferenceException..ctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CurrentUICulture()
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at System.SR.InternalGetResourceString(System.String)
   at System.SR.GetResourceString(System.String)
   at System.NullReferenceException..ctor()
   at xxx (related to my code)
```

Comment: Is your app setting `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` at all?

Comment: No. I haven't set that. Can it solve the problem? I have just try to set it as InvariantCulture at the beginning of my program and test again. It is strange if I must set  this in all my programs every time.

Comment: I have run these 2 lines in the beginning of my program but the problem still exists: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; How can I solve it?

Comment: It is crashing over and over again on trying to retrieve the exception string from the current UI culture.  Admirable that they can detect this mishap without crashing the program with a StackOverflowException.  Probably inspired by bug reports from some very confounded programmers.  Easy fix: don't change the CurrentUICulture to InvariantCulture, it is only suitable for formatting.  Your user is always particular about the language they speak and read.

Comment: From https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72381 - _"The "infinite recursion during resource lookup" is generic symptom of the things going wrong and the process state being corrupted. If you see this error message, it is unlikely to be a duplicate of the problem tracked by this issue"_